# How do I change the position of a static block in my product view?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, layout, custom

I am applying a custom design to one of my products. I am using

```
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="moscow-mule-product-header">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>moscow-mule-product-header</block_id></action>
     </block> 
 </reference>
```

My problem is that I need my static block below the header of the page but above the product details. Currently it is displaying below the product information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope you want manged from Custom design tab from admin

just use `before="-"` for start of all content{`<reference name="content">}` area div

```
  <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="moscow-mule-product-header" before="-" >

                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>>moscow-mule-product-header</block_id></action>
            </block>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tags `before` and `after` applies for this case. Some documentation about this [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484955/magento-xml-using-before-after-to-place-blocks-hardly-ever-works) is an answer you might find useful too.
Basically

```
<block type="core/template" name="example_block" before="content" template="page/html/example-block.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add this code in your `config.xml` file.

```
#Location:app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/catalog.xml
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="cms/block" name="moscow-mule-product-header" as="my_custom_block">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>moscow-mule-product-header</block_id></action>
         </block> 
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now go to your `view.phtml` file and call your cms block wherever you need. For me if you call this cms block just below this section

```
#Location:app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml (Normal Case)
<div class="product-shop">
     <div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
     </div>
     <div> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_block'); ?></div>
     .......
</div>
```

It will show your cms block just below the name of product. You can use

```
<div> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_custom_block'); ?></div>
```

anywhere you need inside `view.phtml`.

Hope it helps